# SharePoint Designer 2010 List Forms

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Are SharePoint 2010 Designer List Forms portable or custom rendering templates still the best way to customize the List Forms? InfoPath 2010 is out of question because of enterprise licensing issues.

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the extent of your customization. You can achieve quiate a lot with the standard DataFromWebPart and custom XSLT but if you want to add custom controls you'll run into problems (as highlighted here http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/01/26/extending-the-dataform-web-part-to-allow-custom-field-controls.aspx).

For extensive customization the best bet is to create a custom webpart and include it on the edit form. Bear in mind that field controls automatically pick up and update content from the SPContext object so calling SPContext.Current.Listitem.Update() is enough to save the values of all field controls in your custom webpart. Of course if you're using standard asp.net control on there as well you'll need to pickup and set their values manually.

Comment: Thanks Chaholl. I ended up implementing it via custom rendering templates.